# How can I display a HTML5 page

Tags: ios, html

I created an HTML5 page using Google Web Designer.
[Here](http://finedine.s3.amazonaws.com/finedine_ads/video_ad.html)

In the simulator, autoplay function is not working properly.

Also video is duplicated like in the image below.

[image]

The code that I am using to show is:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://finedine.s3.amazonaws.com/finedine_ads/video_ad.html"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 10.0];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Update: I display this with the code below:

```
    if(!adView.isBeingPresented){
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
        adView= (AdViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"AdViewController"];
    }
   if(![adView isBeingPresented])
      [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentViewController:adView];
        //[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:adView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: what about that popup view, is it a third part library? what is its relevant code ?

Comment: I updated, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Autoplay wont work when embedding webviews because of restrictions, the `video.play()` must be called at some kind of touch interaction on the web page.

> ### User Control of Downloads Over Cellular Networks
>
> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript `play()` and `load()` methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the `play()` or `load()` method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an `onLoad="play()"` event does not.

- Read more at [iOS-Specific Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) on the Apple Development Portal.

---

About the dual screen showing in the video, this is youtube who is providing a 3d version of the embedded video. I haven't used Google Web Designer but there might be a some kind of settings to load another kind of video.